# Syntax to remove record when build subset from other tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a complex SQLite query I could use some help crafting. I have 5 tables, each with 3 columns. col3 of tables 1 through 4 is a foreign key to table5 col1.

I need to select distinct values of col3 in tables 1 thru 4 and remove col1 of table5 if col1 of table5 is not in the selection result.

```
Table1
col1   col2   col3
a        b      1
c        d      2
e        f      1

Table2
col1   col2   col3
g       h      2
i       j      3
k       l      4
m       n      2

Table3
col1   col2   col3
b       a      4
d       c      3
o       p      8
q       r      1

Table4
col1   col2   col3
s       t      2
u       v      3
w       x      4

Table5
col1   col2   col3
1      aa      bb
2      cc      dd
3      ee      ff
4      gg      hh
5      ii      jj
6      kk      ll
7      mm      nn
8      oo      pp
```

The distinct set from tables 1 through 4 would be.
    1
    2
    3 
    4
    8

and the records removed from table5 would be
    5
    6
    7

As far as I have gotten is collecting the selection set with this code...

```
SELECT [table1].[col3], 1 as tablenumber
FROM [table1]
GROUP BY [table1].[col3_ID]
UNION ALL
SELECT [table2].[col3_ID], 2 as tablenumber
FROM [table2]
GROUP BY [table2].[col3_ID]
UNION ALL
SELECT [table3].[col3], 3 as tablenumber
FROM [table3]
GROUP BY [table3].[col3]
UNION ALL
SELECT [table4].[col3], 4 as tablenumber
FROM [table4]
GROUP BY [table4].[col3]
UNION ALL
```

I would like to remove the records from table5 in the same operation.

Comment: What do you mean with "distinct" (your query does not return distinct values)? And what do you mean with "remove"; do you want to exclude records from the selection result, or do you want to delete records from table5?

Comment: I would like to delete table5 records. The union all command is returning the expected result set which is a distinct record for any record in the tables 1 thru 4. should it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to get the list of id's to be deleted:

```
select *
from table5
where col1 not in (select col3 from table1 union
                   select col3 from table2 union
                   select col3 from table3 union
                   select col3 from table4
                 );
```

The following `delete` should work to actually remove them:

```
delete from table5
where col1 not in (select col3 from table1 union
                   select col3 from table2 union
                   select col3 from table3 union
                   select col3 from table4
                 );
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!7/fbbf4) is a SQL Fiddle to show them in action.

(The original answer was incorrect.  Among the reasons was the extra set of parentheses around the subqueries in the `union`.)

Comment: Your query is not working the error says syntax error near UNION.

Comment: @htm11h . . . I fixed the answer.  Learned something new about SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete records and return records to your application in the same operation.
You have to execute two statements:

```
DELETE FROM Table5
WHERE col1 NOT IN (SELECT col3 FROM Table1 UNION
                   SELECT col3 FROM Table2 UNION
                   SELECT col3 FROM Table3 UNION
                   SELECT col3 FROM Table4);

SELECT col3 FROM Table1 UNION
SELECT col3 FROM Table2 UNION
SELECT col3 FROM Table3 UNION
SELECT col3 FROM Table4;
```

If you want them to be atomic, wrap them into a [transaction](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html).

Comment: I think you missed a NOT in the WHERE clause. Thank you for the code sample though.  where col1 not in